# WaveSurfer.js - Play and control multiple tracks at the same time

Tags: javascript, wavesurfer.js

I am working with https://wavesurfer-js.org and I have 10 different tracks loading on a page. I need to be able to control all of them at the same time.

Currently, I am playing them like this

```
tracks.forEach(function(track){

            track.on('ready', function(){
                track.play();
            });

        });
```

The problem is that they start as soon as they are ready so they are not in sync.

How can I wait for all of them to be ready?
How could I manage all of them simultaneously so when I skip to a certain point, all of them do?

Thanks

Comment: I think you need `Promise.all()`?: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: @Amy Thank you, I managed to solve the first problem, do you have any hints for being able to control all of the tracks simultaneously ?

Comment: @C.Ovidiu have you managed to do this. I need some help on this. Would you like to post more here.

Comment: @Mustkeem Hi, unfortunatelly I couldn't do it with wavesurfer, in the end I did it all manually in javascript without using any library.

Comment: @C.Ovidiu thanks for reply. I am trying to achieve this in reactjs. But it seems pain in back.

Comment: @Mustkeem Hey, if you didn't fine out yet, there is an excellent playlist plugin for this, and I am using it with excellent results. Here it is https://github.com/naomiaro/waveform-playlist